# XSL Finding other Nodes values in an xml tree using the current Contexts ID pt 2

Tags: xml, xslt

This is a slightly updated question that was originally posted here: [XSL - Finding another nodes value using the value of the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998907/xsl-finding-another-nodes-value-using-the-value-of-the-current-context) . 
I have an XML that uses PackageID values to reference other nodes in the document.

I want to create a for-each loop for each CompositionPackage that has the Operation value of 'Rasta'. Note: a CompositionPackage can have more than one Match. 
I would like to use the result of the current node to then find the value of another node containing the returned PackageID value in the document. 
In this case I want to get the value of SourcePackage/PackageName or MaterialPackage/PackageName or another CompositionPackage that has a matching PackageID value to that found in CompositionPackage/PackageTracks/TimelineTrack/TrackSegment/SourcePackageID.

Sample XML:

```
<AAG version="1.1">
<Preface>
  <ContentStorage>
      <SourcePackage>
        <PackageTracks>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
                <ComponentLength>5066</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          </TimelineTrack>
        </PackageTracks>
        <PackageName>Name001</PackageName>
        <PackageID>urn:44f70006</PackageID>
      </SourcePackage>
      <MaterialPackage>
        <PackageTracks>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
            <ComponentLength>804</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          </TimelineTrack>
        </PackageTracks>
        <PackageName>Name010</PackageName>
        <PackageID>urn:44f70008</PackageID>
      </MaterialPackage>
      <CompositionPackage>
        <PackageTracks>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
                <Operation>Rasta</Operation>
                <SourcePackageID>urn:44f70006</SourcePackageID>
                <ComponentLength>10099</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          </TimelineTrack>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
                <Operation>NotRasta</Operation>
                <SourcePackageID>urn:44f70007</SourcePackageID>
                <ComponentLength>100</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
                <Operation>Rasta</Operation>
                <SourcePackageID>urn:44f70008</SourcePackageID>
                <ComponentLength>200</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          </TimelineTrack>
          </TimelineTrack>
        </PackageTracks>
        <PackageName>NameABC</PackageName>
        <PackageID>urn:ce1904fd</PackageID>
      </CompositionPackage>
      <CompositionPackage>
        <PackageTracks>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
                <Operation>Rasta</Operation>
                <SourcePackageID>urn:00f70009</SourcePackageID>
                <ComponentLength>222</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          </TimelineTrack>
        </PackageTracks>
        <PackageName>NameABC</PackageName>
        <PackageID>urn:ff1603fd</PackageID>
      </CompositionPackage>
      <CompositionPackage>
        <PackageTracks>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
                <Operation>Rasta</Operation>
                <SourcePackageID>urn:11f80008</SourcePackageID>
                <ComponentLength>444</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          </TimelineTrack>
        </PackageTracks>
        <PackageName>NameBCD</PackageName>
        <PackageID>urn:gg1702fj</PackageID>
      </CompositionPackage>
      <CompositionPackage>
        <PackageTracks>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
                <Operation>Rasta</Operation>
                <SourcePackageID>urn:22f90009</SourcePackageID>
                <ComponentLength>555</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          </TimelineTrack>
        </PackageTracks>
        <PackageName>NameXYZ</PackageName>
        <PackageID>urn:11f80010</PackageID>
      </CompositionPackage>
      <CompositionPackage>
        <PackageTracks>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
                <Operation>NotRasta</Operation>
                <SourcePackageID>urn:22f90009</SourcePackageID>
                <ComponentLength>555</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          </TimelineTrack>
        </PackageTracks>
        <PackageName>NameWWW</PackageName>
        <PackageID>urn:11f80008</PackageID>
      </CompositionPackage>
      <MaterialPackage>
        <PackageTracks>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
            <ComponentLength>864</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          </TimelineTrack>
        </PackageTracks>
        <PackageName>Name008</PackageName>
        <PackageID>urn:00f70009</PackageID>
      </MaterialPackage>
      <MaterialPackage>
        <PackageTracks>
          <TimelineTrack>
            <TrackSegment>
            <ComponentLength>864</ComponentLength>
            </TrackSegment>
          </TimelineTrack>
        </PackageTracks>
        <PackageName>Name002</PackageName>
        <PackageID>urn:22f70009</PackageID>
      </MaterialPackage>
  </ContentStorage>
</Preface>
</AAG>
```

Sample XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match = "AAG">
 <Master>
 <xsl:for-each select="AAG/Preface/ContentStorage/CompositionPackage/PackageTracks/TimelineTrack/TrackSegment/Operation"> <!--whose Operation value is 'Rasta' -->
 <newnode>
   <value1><xsl:value-of select ="CompositionPackage/PackageTracks/TimelineTrack/TrackSegment/ComponentLength"/></value1>
   <value2><xsl:value-of select ="CompositionPackage/PackageTracks/TimelineTrack/TrackSegment/SourcePackageID"/></value2>
   <value3><xsl:value-of select ="CompositionPackage/PackageTracks/TimelineTrack/TrackSegment[SourcePackageID=current()/MaterialPackage/PackageName"/></value3>
 </newnode>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </Master>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected XML:

```
<Master>
<newnode>
  <Value1>1099</Value1>
  <Value2>urn:44f70006</Value2>
  <Value3>Name001</Value3>
</newnode>
<newnode>
  <Value1>200</Value1>
  <Value2>urn:44f70008</Value2>
  <Value3>Name010</Value3>
</newnode>
<newnode>
  <Value1>222</Value1>
  <Value2>urn:00f70009</Value2>
  <Value3>Name008</Value3>
</newnode>
<newnode>
  <Value1>444</Value1>
  <Value2>urn:11f80008</Value2>
  <Value3>NameWWW</Value3>
</newnode>
<newnode>
  <Value1>555</Value1>
  <Value2>urn:22f90009</Value2>
  <Value3>Name002</Value3>
</newnode>
</Master>
```

My Current XSL is returning "" for all value3 elements.

Comment: The provided result contradicts the provided XML file: There isn't any `PackageID` element with value "urn:22f90009". Therefore, in the last `newnode` in the provided result, `Value3` must be empty -- but in the provided result it has a non-empty string value.

Comment: Also, in the source XML document there are nested `TimelineTrack` elements -- this seems like an error... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The error is obvious**: inside a

```
<xsl:for-each select=
"AAG
  /Preface
    /ContentStorage
      /CompositionPackage
         /PackageTracks/TimelineTrack/TrackSegment/Operation">
```

**You have**:

```
<xsl:value-of select =
 "CompositionPackage/PackageTracks/TimelineTrack/TrackSegment/ComponentLength"/>
```

**As an `Operation` element doesn't have any `CompositionPackage` children (and in fact doesn't have any element children at all),  the above selects nothing and nothing is output**.

Exactly the same case for the other two `xsl:value-of` instructions inside the body of `xsl:for-each`

**There are contradictions between the provided XML document and the wanted result and there are data errors**:

1. There isn't any `PackageID` element with value "urn:22f90009". Therefore, in the last `newnode` in the provided result, `Value3` must be empty -- but in the provided result it has a non-empty string value.
2. In the source XML document there are nested `TimelineTrack` elements.

**These issues explain why the transformation I came up with doesn't exactly produce the wanted result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match = "AAG">
       <Master>
         <xsl:for-each select=
         "Preface
           /ContentStorage
            /CompositionPackage
               /PackageTracks
                 /TimelineTrack
                   /TrackSegment[Operation='Rasta']
         ">
             <newnode>
               <value1>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ComponentLength"/>
               </value1>
               <value2>
                 <xsl:value-of select="SourcePackageID"/>
           </value2>
               <value3>
                 <xsl:value-of select=
                  "../../../../*[self::SourcePackage
                       or self::MaterialPackage
                       or self::CompositionPackage]
                                    [PackageID
                                    =
                                    current()/SourcePackageID
                                    ]
                                    /PackageName
                     "/>
               </value3>
             </newnode>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </Master>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<AAG version="1.1">
    <Preface>
        <ContentStorage>
            <SourcePackage>
                <PackageTracks>
                    <TimelineTrack>
                        <TrackSegment>
                            <ComponentLength>5066</ComponentLength>
                        </TrackSegment>
                    </TimelineTrack>
                </PackageTracks>
                <PackageName>Name001</PackageName>
                <PackageID>urn:44f70006</PackageID>
            </SourcePackage>
            <MaterialPackage>
                <PackageTracks>
                    <TimelineTrack>
                        <TrackSegment>
                            <ComponentLength>804</ComponentLength>
                        </TrackSegment>
                    </TimelineTrack>
                </PackageTracks>
                <PackageName>Name010</PackageName>
                <PackageID>urn:44f70008</PackageID>
            </MaterialPackage>
            <CompositionPackage>
                <PackageTracks>
                    <TimelineTrack>
                        <TrackSegment>
                            <Operation>Rasta</Operation>
                            <SourcePackageID>urn:44f70006</SourcePackageID>
                            <ComponentLength>10099</ComponentLength>
                        </TrackSegment>
                    </TimelineTrack>
                    <TimelineTrack>
                        <TrackSegment>
                            <Operation>NotRasta</Operation>
                            <SourcePackageID>urn:44f70007</SourcePackageID>
                            <ComponentLength>100</ComponentLength>
                        </TrackSegment>
                        <TimelineTrack>
                            <TrackSegment>
                                <Operation>Rasta</Operation>
                                <SourcePackageID>urn:44f70008</SourcePackageID>
                                <ComponentLength>200</ComponentLength>
                            </TrackSegment>
                        </TimelineTrack>
                    </TimelineTrack>
                </PackageTracks>
                <PackageName>NameABC</PackageName>
                <PackageID>urn:ce1904fd</PackageID>
            </CompositionPackage>
            <CompositionPackage>
                <PackageTracks>
                    <TimelineTrack>
                        <TrackSegment>
                            <Operation>Rasta</Operation>
                            <SourcePackageID>urn:00f70009</SourcePackageID>
                            <ComponentLength>222</ComponentLength>
                        </TrackSegment>
                    </TimelineTrack>
                </PackageTracks>
                <PackageName>NameABC</PackageName>
                <PackageID>urn:ff1603fd</PackageID>
            </CompositionPackage>
            <CompositionPackage>
                <PackageTracks>
                    <TimelineTrack>
                        <TrackSegment>
                            <Operation>Rasta</Operation>
                            <SourcePackageID>urn:11f80008</SourcePackageID>
                            <ComponentLength>444</ComponentLength>
                        </TrackSegment>
                    </TimelineTrack>
                </PackageTracks>
                <PackageName>NameBCD</PackageName>
                <PackageID>urn:gg1702fj</PackageID>
            </CompositionPackage>
            <CompositionPackage>
                <PackageTracks>
                    <TimelineTrack>
                        <TrackSegment>
                            <Operation>Rasta</Operation>
                            <SourcePackageID>urn:22f90009</SourcePackageID>
                            <ComponentLength>555</ComponentLength>
                        </TrackSegment>
                    </TimelineTrack>
                </PackageTracks>
                <PackageName>NameXYZ</PackageName>
                <PackageID>urn:11f80010</PackageID>
            </CompositionPackage>
            <CompositionPackage>
                <PackageTracks>
                    <TimelineTrack>
                        <TrackSegment>
                            <Operation>NotRasta</Operation>
                            <SourcePackageID>urn:22f90009</SourcePackageID>
                            <ComponentLength>555</ComponentLength>
                        </TrackSegment>
                    </TimelineTrack>
                </PackageTracks>
                <PackageName>NameWWW</PackageName>
                <PackageID>urn:11f80008</PackageID>
            </CompositionPackage>
            <MaterialPackage>
                <PackageTracks>
                    <TimelineTrack>
                        <TrackSegment>
                            <ComponentLength>864</ComponentLength>
                        </TrackSegment>
                    </TimelineTrack>
                </PackageTracks>
                <PackageName>Name008</PackageName>
                <PackageID>urn:00f70009</PackageID>
            </MaterialPackage>
            <MaterialPackage>
                <PackageTracks>
                    <TimelineTrack>
                        <TrackSegment>
                            <ComponentLength>864</ComponentLength>
                        </TrackSegment>
                    </TimelineTrack>
                </PackageTracks>
                <PackageName>Name002</PackageName>
                <PackageID>urn:22f70009</PackageID>
            </MaterialPackage>
        </ContentStorage>
    </Preface>
</AAG>
```

**the following result is produced:**

```
<Master>
    <newnode>
        <value1>10099</value1>
        <value2>urn:44f70006</value2>
        <value3>Name001</value3>
    </newnode>
    <newnode>
        <value1>222</value1>
        <value2>urn:00f70009</value2>
        <value3>Name008</value3>
    </newnode>
    <newnode>
        <value1>444</value1>
        <value2>urn:11f80008</value2>
        <value3>NameWWW</value3>
    </newnode>
    <newnode>
        <value1>555</value1>
        <value2>urn:22f90009</value2>
        <value3></value3>
    </newnode>
</Master>
```